# Brahma with hundreds of heads

Tags: puranas, brahma, chaitanya-charitamrita

In the [Chaitanya Charitamrta (Madhya Lila, Chapter 21)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/21/67/), we hear of Brahmas with hundreds of heads. Are there any Puranic reference for the same?